# Using HighCharts is it possible to center line points over 1 column in column group?

Tags: highcharts

In this HighCharts graph you can see a line over groupings of 3 columns. The data for the line is the same data as the third column.

I would like to show the line's points centered over the 3rd column in each column group. Is there a way to do that with HighCharts?

[image: HighCharts column and line graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can find to do this is to give the line series a `pointStart` value that shifts it to the right.

```
       {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Joe\'s Line',
            data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 1],
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                fillColor: 'white'
            },
            pointStart: 0.20 //force it to start further right.
        }
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t2Qqa/).

[image]

Comment: Sweet! That worked great. Thank you for the tip. The only thing left to figure out is how to recenter the marker when a category is hidden (i.e. one of the columns) when someone deselects a category from the legend.

Comment: Note: There is a side effect using pointStart. The values returned by this.category in my tooltip formatter are now the pointStart value and not the year which they were previously.